# simple confirm popup if some condition met in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a view with a hidden field

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Driver.ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "driver" } })
```

I have a controller with a method I want to call passing that field "driver", but debugging I see this method doesn't even get called.

```
public string GetEditWarningMessage(int? driverID)
{
    Driver driver = unitOfWork.DriverRepository.Get().Where(d => d.ID == driverID).FirstOrDefault();
    string message = null;
     if(!driver.Status.Equals("A"))
    {

        message = "This driver is assigned to current or future schedule movements";
    }

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);
}
```

and finally the javascript, which I'm sure is the source of the problem

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#driver").change(function () {
        $.get("../GetEditWarningMessage/" + $(this).val() + '?' + $.now(), function (response) {

            var warning;
            warning = $.parseJSON(response);
        });

        $("form").submit(function () {
            var performEdit = false;

            if (warning != null) {

                performEdit = confirm(warning);

                return performDelete;
            }

        });
    });
});
```

basically if the message I pass from the GetEditWarningMessage() is null, I don't want the popup to appear, otherwise have it popup with the warning message passed on.

Help much appreciated, thank you all

Comment: Does anything change that hidden field value? If not then 'change' method won't be hit at all...

Comment: no it doesn't, it's just a static field hidden to user, then what else besides "change" can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
$.get("../GetEditWarningMessage/" + $(this).val() + '?' + $.now(), function (response) {

        var warning;
        warning = $.parseJSON(response);
    });
```

To

```
var warning;
$.get("../GetEditWarningMessage/" + $(this).val() + '?' + $.now(), function (response) {


        warning = $.parseJSON(response);
    });
```

In your code the variable "warning" has scope inside only $.get call. So it cannot be used in form submit call..
Declaring it outside the $.get call will solve the issue.

If the hidden input value doesn't change then you must call **GetEditWarningMessage** inside the form submit call.. even that Synchronous ajax call so that form submittion can wait for the response of warning message.

Comment: I have done this and it works like this         $.get("../GetEditWarningMessage/" + $("#driver").val(), function (response) {
, it calls the GetWarningMessage but the parameter driver passed on is null